# Why is my counter not incrementing when OnTriggerEnter is called?

Tags: c#, collision-detection, unity

I have a script that handles the destruction of game objects based on what they collide with.  I am trying to count the number of objects destroyed when they collide with specific objects.  However, this is not happening.  Instead, the counter is getting to "1" and no longer counting.  Can anyone explain why?

```
public class Destroy:MonoBehaviour{
    public GameObject asteroid_explosion;
    public GameObject ship_explosion;
    private int destroy_count = 0;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        if(other.tag == "Boundary"){
            return;
        }

        if(other.tag == "Bolt"){
            destroy_count = destroy_count + 1;
            Instantiate(asteroid_explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            Debug.Log(destroy_count);
        }

        if(other.tag == "Player"){
            destroy_count = destroy_count + 1;
            Instantiate(ship_explosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
        }
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `destroy_count` variable is class level, and after collision you are destroying the gameObject have this script attached. So every object will reach at max at 1 and then destroy :)

Comment: So I need to change it from a private to a public variable?

Comment: No, you need to update public variable of another class or any static variable if you have any class having all global variables

Comment: For example, you have a class named `Globals` and that class having all the global variables. Like, `public static float DESTROY_COUNT = 0;` then you can access it from any where by, `Globals.DESTROY_COUNT`. Hope you got my point

Comment: Ah ok, I think I get it now.  So if I were to declare the variable in the GameControlelr script, I would need to access it within the Destroy class in the Destroy script and increment it that way?

Comment: Exactly. You are right :)

Comment: This helped me a lot.